# failing to get value from select (value is not defined)

Tags: javascript, opentok

I'm trying to get a value from a select options list I have, that I also generate through javascript but I'm unable to retrieve it for some reason.

```
var a, i, v;

v = document.querySelector('#video-setting');
a = document.querySelector('#audio-setting');

i = 0;

while (i < audioInputDevices.length) {
  a.innerHTML += '<option value=' + audioInputDevices[i].deviceId + '>' + audioInputDevices[i].label + '</option>';
  i++;
}

i = 0;

while (i < videoInputDevices.length) {
  v.innerHTML += '<option value=' + videoInputDevices[i].deviceId + '>' + videoInputDevices[i].label + '</option>';
  i++;
}

return;
var publisherOptions;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var au, audioValue, vi, videoValue;
  au = document.getElementById("audio-setting");
  audioValue = au.options[au.selectedIndex].value;
  vi = document.getElementById("video-setting");
  videoValue = vi.options[vi.selectedIndex].value;
});

publisherOptions = {
  audioSource: audioValue,
  videoSource: videoValue
};
```

and my HTML:

```
<select id="video-setting"></select>
<select id="audio-setting"></select>
```

now the error I get is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: audioValue is not defined
```

Comment: You have declared "audioValue" & "videoValue" inside document.ready callback, and then you are trying to assign them to an object literal in a total different scope..

Answer (score 3):

Because you are defining your variables inside your anonymous function. Therefore they are not visible to the outer scope code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var au, audioValue, vi, videoValue; //this defines local scope variables
                                      //won't be visible outside this function
  ...
});
```

To solve this, since your publisherOptions variable is global, just set your publisherOptions variable inside the ready callback as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    publisherOptions = {
        audioSource: audioValue,
        videoSource: videoValue
    };
});
```

Comment: problem is if I put publisherOptions in the function, I have stuff that is reliant on that. Evil circle. When I tried to remove document ready I got Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: @SebastianJenningsAlmnes, Your publisherOptions is global scope, whatever is reliant on it will still have access to it. Just don't put the `var publisherOptions` line inside the ready callback leave it where it is.

Comment: @PatrickEvans when I do that I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined' and it points to my value in the audioValue variable

Comment: @SebastianJenningsAlmnes, then it sounds like that code is running before  your `.ready()` callback is called, it should be run after

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery ready function fires first before your vanilla JavaScript. So when it's tiring to set the audioValue it's going to be undefined. You could wrap the JavaScript inside of a closure or drop it inside of the jQuery ready statement.

That should work.